# UnknownHostException: Connection error when running Airflow DAG with PySpark and Docker Compose

Tags: docker, pyspark, docker-compose, airflow

I am setting up a workflow using Airflow, PySpark, and a PostgreSQL database, all running in Docker Compose. However, when I execute the DAG file in Airflow's UI, I encounter the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.jdbc. : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: test_db_3
```

It seems like Airflow is unable to resolve the hostname "test_db_3" when attempting to establish a connection to the database.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue and establish a successful connection to the PostgreSQL database within the Airflow DAG?

PS: I wanted to establish a DockerOperator so that I do not have to install all the pyspark dependencies on the airflow docker to separate the services better.

My docker-compose file:

```
`---
version: '3.4'

x-common:
  &common
  image: apache/airflow:2.3.0
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0"
  env_file: 
    - .env
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - ./services/backend/src:/opt/airflow/dags

x-depends-on:
  &depends-on
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
    airflow-init:
      condition: service_completed_successfully


services:

  backend:
    build: ./services/backend
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://template:template@db:5432/template_db
    volumes:
      - ./services/backend:/app
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: uvicorn src.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 --workers 2
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: test_db_3
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=template
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=template
      - POSTGRES_DB=template_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./sample_data:/sample_data

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin2_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: dna@europe.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  scheduler:
      <<: [*common, *depends-on]
      container_name: airflow-scheduler_2
      command: scheduler
      restart: on-failure
      ports:
        - "8793:8793"
      depends_on:
      - db

  webserver:
      <<: [*common, *depends-on]
      container_name: airflow-webserver_2
      restart: always
      command: webserver
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 5
      depends_on:
      - db
    
  airflow-init:
      <<: *common
      container_name: airflow-init_2
      entrypoint: /bin/bash
      command:
        - -c
        - |
          mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
          chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
          exec /entrypoint airflow version
      depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin-data:
  postgres-db-volume: `
```

DAG file:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator

from datetime import datetime

with DAG(
    dag_id='first_sample_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 28),
    schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
    
    read_csv_to_table = DockerOperator(
        task_id='read_csv_to_table',
        image='airflow-backend:latest',
        command="python3 /app/main.py", 
        network_mode='bridge')

read_csv_to_table
```

[Link to the full code in GitHub](https://github.com/kaumujoshi/airflow)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions are networks. You have to add networks to your docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

x-common:
  &common
  image: apache/airflow:2.3.0
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0"
  env_file: 
    - .env
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

x-depends-on:
  &depends-on
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
    airflow-init:
      condition: service_completed_successfully

services:

  backend:
   .....

    networks:             # Add this networks section
      - your_network_name

  db:
    ....
    networks:             # Add this networks section
      - your_network_name

  pgadmin:
    ....
    networks:             # Add this networks section
      - your_network_name

  postgres:
    ...
    networks:             # Add this networks section
      - your_network_name

  scheduler:
      ...
      networks:             # Add this networks section
        - your_network_name

  webserver:
      ...
      networks:             # Add this networks section
        - your_network_name
    
  airflow-init:
      ...
      networks:             # Add this networks section
        - your_network_name

networks:
  your_network_name:  # Add this network definition
    driver: bridge     # Use the bridge driver or specify a different driver if needed
```

Then the airflow docker should be able to find your database by specifying network_mode='your_network_name'.